# How to create webservices with struts2 in Eclipse or in Netbeans?

Tags: java

please help me to creating webservice with struts 2 either be using of Eclipse or be using of Netbeans.

Comment: OK. What do you want exactly? Your question does not till me any thing useful

Comment: @Salman I have a Struts2 application, i want to add a SOAP based webservice in this application.
you can use Eclipse IDE or Netbeans IDE for this.

Comment: I have a web application in Struts 2 in Netbeans. If i add a SOAP based web service in this application and run it then i got a error.

localhost:8080/Struts2Test/MyService?wsdl

HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name MyService.

so how we configure SOAP webservice with Struts 2.

Comment: I recommend to write new question with the new error you are getting and you should include clear explanation for your use-case. Have a look to this [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) so you will avoid the vote down in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First you need to know to basic idea behind `Web Services` and how it works:

  [A short introduction to Web Services](http://acs.lbl.gov/projects/gtg/projects/pyGridWare/doc/tutorial/html/x284.html)
- Then, you need to generate `Java` classes from the given `WSDL` file(if there is one, otherwise you need to communicate through SOAP directly):

  [Creating Java Classes from WSDL file using Apache Axis 2](http://www.gerd-riesselmann.net/scala/creating-java-classes-wsdl-file-using-apache-axis-2)

  [Generating Java code from a WSDL document](http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/Programmers_Guide/ws_wsdl5.htm)

  **Note**: The reference given using `Apache Axis 2`. There are others ways to do the same task this one of them.
- Also, you need to deal with `Certificates` issue (if it is required). I can not tell much about it. Since, it depends on your case.
- Now you can work with your `Java application`, where you need to establish `SSL` connection, send `requests` and receive `response` from the `Server` you are requesting services form it.

Comment: thank's for your reply. but i already have a web application in Struts 2 and if i want to add a webservice in this application than how i configure.